# Sugar gives Unicode SQL error only when connected with a particular server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sugarcrm

I have installed sugarCRM with SQL Server. This has been functioning since the last couple of years. We setup another SQL Server as a UAT server. For the UAT server we took a backup of the live database and restored it on the server. When we connect to the new instance, by changing the settings in sugar, it gives the error :

> SQL Error : Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

When the same database is restored to the original server it works fine. We checked the versions of SQL Server are exactly the same.

- Only difference is that the new server is running inside a Hypervisor, so in the end of the version is says (Hypervisor)
- If I try to connect to the original server with an IP address, it gives me the same error as well. With a host name 'abcsrv' it works correctly.
- I tried assigning a host name to the new server, but still the same.
- I am able to telnet to both the servers from my web-server.

The SQL Servers are version 2008 R2, the web-server with sugar is Centos.

I understand the error talks about Unicode data and there are some solutions that are suggested to this problem that use `cast` and try to fix it. My understanding is, if the code is working with one server of the exact same version, it should be able to work with the other one as well, also, I am not too keen on going into the SugarCRM code and start altering queries.

Any pointers on what could be the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Go to /etc/freetds.conf

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 7.0
```

Or if you have defined a specific connection change that tds version value inside the connection.

It did worked for me with the same error on SugarCRM on Centos + MSSQL 2008 R2 .